# C# MVC DropDownListFor in a table of editable records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I am not sure if this is possible, and have not found any similar questions on this.

We have an Edit View that is NOT for a single record, but for the multiple members of a "parent" record. These "child" record need to be edited together (at the same time). ... if possible.

One field in each of these "child" records is a reference to another table, so a select list is required. We use DropDownListFor in all of our standard Edit Views, and the single record edits fine.

Our model for this issue is :

```
    [Display(Name = "Team Member")]
    public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Team Member")]
    public String Contact_Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type/Role")]
    public int MemberTypeLookUp_ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Type/Role")]
    public String MemberTypeValue { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Type/Role")]
    public LookUpList MemberTypeLookUp { get; set; }
```

We retrieve the first 4 fields via a select from a database table. Straightforward and OK..

Our code to set up the DropDownListFor is :

(edit : new code added within the foreach() loop to manually set the .Selected property of the relevant option within each list to true. This still does not translate over to the actual displayed View...)

```
    foreach (TeamEditViewItem tevi in this.members)
    {
        tevi.MemberTypeLookUp = new LookUpList("TeamMemberType");

        foreach (SelectListItem item in tevi.MemberTypeLookUp.list)
        {
            if (item.Value == tevi.MemberTypeLookUp_ID.ToString())
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

For completion of this question, the LookUpList code is :

```
public class LookUpList 
{
    public SelectList list;

    // Return all Active LookUp entries for the passed-in Category.
    public LookUpList(String Category)
    {
        WorkpointContext _db = new WorkpointContext();

        int Customer_ID = _db.GetCustomer_ID();

        IList<LookUp> items = (from lookup in _db.LookUp
                                where (lookup.Category == Category)
                                && (lookup.IsActive == true)
                                orderby lookup.DisplayOrder ascending
                                select lookup).ToList();

        this.list = new SelectList(items, "ID", "Value");
    }

}
```

As mentioned, the LookUpList code is fine for a single record on a standard Edit View.

After rendering the page, we get the multiple "child" records listed, however the DropDown List does not hold the existing value for each record. (This is an EDIT not a Create, so values have already been assigned via defaults and other logics - not via DropDown lists on the Create View.

When viewing the source of the page, I can see that each of the DropDown Lists have their own ID.

I have a feeling that our issue is due to the multiple DropDownListFor objects on the page, but cannot figure out WHAT the issue is and WHY we have the issue.

Our View has simple code for the DropDownList :

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp_ID, Model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp.list, "--Select--")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp_ID)
```

The third parameter has been added because we were always getting the first option in the DropDown Lists and needed to determine if there was a value or not.
We are constantly getting the "--Select--" option displayed in the DropDown Lists, which is a placeholder and not a valid option - therefore the Validation Message is displayed.

(Edit) I have added the complete Edit View cshtml code :

```
@model WebWorkPoint.Models.TeamEditView
<h3>Edit Team</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
        @if (Model.members.Count>0)
        {
            <table>
            <!-- table headings -->
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid black; " >
                    <div class='editor-label'>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.members.First().Contact_Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="spacer-border"> </td>
                <td style="text-align:center; border-bottom: 1px solid black; " >
                    <div class='editor-label'>
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.members.First().MemberTypeValue)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <!-- table rows -->
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.members.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; " >
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.members[i].Contact_ID)
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.members[i].Contact_Name)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members[i].Contact_Name)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="spacer"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; " >
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp_ID, Model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp.list, "--Select--")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp_ID)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>There are currently no team members defined.</p>
        }
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Update Team" />
            @{
                sAction = "/" + Model.TableNameValue + "/" + Model.TableNameValue + "Show/" + Model.TableRecord_ID.ToString();
                sLinkText = "Cancel";
            }
            <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@sAction'" >@sLinkText</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

(end Edit)

Can anyone shed some light into our issue ?  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Cant spot anything wrong with your view code. Are you sure that you have an `option` with a value that matches the value of `MemberTypeLookUp_ID`?

Comment: Reading through the "View Source" of the page, compared to a typical Edit View, the `id` value **IS** one of the `option` values in the list.  The one thing that **IS** missing is the `selected="selected"` part of a normal dropdown list.  I will try manually setting the relevant option during the "manual" `foreach()` loop when setting up the View in the Controller.

Comment: Even manually setting the `.Selected` property of the relevant item within each list does not translate over to the View itself. I have updated the `foreach()` code in the original question/issue to show this new code.  I will add here that stepping through the code in debug does everything that is "expected".

Comment: That should not even be necessary. I suspect the issue might be that you have an underscore in the property name `MemberTypeLookUp_ID`. Try  removing the underscore and see if it works.

Comment: No, no luck I am afraid. I thought you may have nailed it because our code may be breaking some weird rule, but the results are the same. I can see the View Source that the underscore has been removed now (ie: `id="members_0__MemberTypeLookUpID" name="members[0].MemberTypeLookUpID"`), but all of the DropDown Lists still have no value selected. Puzzling ...

Comment: Final suggestion: add the following (jquery) script `$('#members_0__MemberTypeLookUpID').each(function () { if ($(this).val() == $(this).parent().val()) { alert('selected');}});`. If you don't get an alert, the ID is not being set correctly (note - based on revised property name)

Comment: Firstly, I must apologise about not responding. We did not think there were any comments.  That was, until we saw the `Show 1 more comment` link/button at the bottom, just recently.  Back to testing : We did not get an alert for `'selected'` - but this was almost "expected", because the `View Source` of the page shows us that no values are `"selected"` when the page is loaded/created. On further debugging, `$this().val()` has a value, but `$(this).parent().val()` **does not** have a value. We continue to investigate what this means ...

Comment: Which goes back to my first comment, i.e. there is something wrong with your code because the value of `MemberTypeLookUpID` is eiher not set (null) or has a value which does not match one of the options, otherwise the script would have created an alert. (PS. it would not have mattered if none or all the options had the selected attribute - the script was not checking for that)

Comment: I have added more alerts around the code, which show us what is being compared. We can see the values as mentioned previously : `$this().val()` has a value, but `$(this).parent().val()` **does not** have a value.  I have run the same script on a normal Edit View of ours, where a `@Html.DropDownListFor` **is** loaded with the selected option correctly - changing the field name of course. EXACTLY the same outcome is achieved (value; no value; and no "Selected" message is displayed). Investigation continues ...

Comment: ... The previous comment means that the suggestion offered works the same for every dropdownlistfor we have, for both straightforward Edit Views that work correctly, to this "problematic" view that we have. This proves either : all of our Edit Views are not set up data correctly (yet somehow all normal Edit Views work) ; or the suggested code does not do what was intended. `$this().val()` has a value, as expected. We do not know what `$(this).parent().val()` is supposed to be or show us. We have interrogated other properties and cannot see another property or value that would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822038/selecteditem-for-multiple-dropdownlistfor-not-being-selected) , we decided to try the same kind of resolution.

As it turns out, the FULL resolution went as follows :

1. We still needed to set up the LookUpList in the setup code (but did not need to attempt any select code) :

   ```
   // other code above ...
   foreach (TeamEditViewItem tevi in this.members)
   {
       tevi.MemberTypeLookUp = new LookUpList("TeamMemberType");
   }
   ```
2. The LookUpList() code creates the SelectList as per the original issue/question - no changes required there.
3. We also needed to replace the DropDownListFor() call on the Edit View :

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp_ID, new SelectList(Model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp.list, "Value", "Text", Model.members[i].MemberTypeLookUp_ID), "--Select--")
   ```

It seemed repetitive or redundant, but this is what was required. There may be something we could do to clean it further, but it "ain't broke" now, so why try to fix it ?

I must say thank you to @Stephen Muecke and @Mario Lopez for their input, to get us investigating and thinking further afield from what we were doing. Also, thank you to @ataravati for resolving the other issue linked above, to get us to try something else.

Hopefully our issue and resolution might help other coders out there ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that all the dropwdowns are being generated with the same Id = MemberTypeLookUp_ID. What I would do is creating a partial view for the child and call it from the main view inside a foreach and pass to this partial view only the child model that has to be populated for and not the whole parent model.

Comment: The id and name fields for each of the records are :

    `id="members_0__MemberTypeLookUp_ID" name="members[0].MemberTypeLookUp_ID"`  
    `id="members_1__MemberTypeLookUp_ID" name="members[1].MemberTypeLookUp_ID"`   
    `id="members_2__MemberTypeLookUp_ID" name="members[2].MemberTypeLookUp_ID"`   

Don't they have different `id` and `name` values ?

... seems I don't know how to format comments ...

Comment: I have run this past the team here. We are not sure what you mean. (I have to admit, we aren't experts on the language)

Comment: Could you paste your view? I think it would be more clear what you are trying to do. thanks.

Comment: I have now added the complete Edit View cshtml code. It is at the end of the original question/issue. Hope this helps.